# how to replace old div with a new one?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to close and create a new div when the countdown hits 0. My div looks like this

```
<div id="bij2">Test
    <div id="bij2Blauw">
        <table width="98%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="titel">Resterende tijd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">
                    <input id="aktie2" type="text" class="countdownTekst" size="27" readonly="readonly">
                    <script language="javascript">
                        countdown(2012, 7, 29, 'aktie2', 'bij2')
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="60">
                    <input name="kopen1" type="submit" class="kopen" id="kopen1" value="Koop nu"
                    />
                </td>
                <td height="60" colspan="2" align="right" valign="bottom">
                    <span class="euro">&#8364;</span>
                    <span class="prijs">14,95</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the countdown

```
function countdown(yr, m, d, idCountdown, divId) {
    var theyear = yr;
    var themonth = m;
    var theday = d;
    var today = new Date();
    var todayy = today.getYear();
    if (todayy < 1000) todayy += 1900
    var todaym = today.getMonth();
    var todayd = today.getDate();
    var todayh = today.getHours();
    var todaymin = today.getMinutes();
    var todaysec = today.getSeconds();
    var todaystring = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec;
    var futurestring = montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr;
    var dd = Date.parse(futurestring) - Date.parse(todaystring);
    var dday = Math.floor(dd / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1);
    var dhour = Math.floor((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1);
    var dmin = Math.floor(((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
    var dsec = Math.floor((((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);
    var dag = "dagen";

    if (dday <= 0 && dhour <= 0 && dmin <= 0 && dsec <= 0) {
        document.getElementById(idCountdown).value = "voorbij";
        $(document.getElementById(divId)).fadeOut(2000);
        //removeElements(document.getElementById(divId));
        setTimeout("creatediv(document.getElementById(divId))", 3000);
        return;
    } else if (dday <= 1) {
        dag = 'dag';
    }
    document.getElementById(idCountdown).value = dday + ' ' + dag + ' ' + dhour + " uur " + dmin + " min " + dsec + " sec";
    setTimeout(function () {
        countdown(theyear, themonth, theday, idCountdown);
    }, 1000);
}
```

So when the time is over it will fade out the div using jQuery. Then i want to create a new div. I use this:

```
function creatediv(id) {

    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
    newdiv.className = 'newclass';
    newdiv.style.float = "left";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "nothing";

    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    alert(id + 'gemaakt');
}
```

But this creates a div at the bottom of the page and i want a new one at the same position as the div that fades out. What do i need to change?

Comment: Please remove jQuery from your tags

Comment: But if you're going to be using jQuery anyway, there's simpler ways to select the DIV you want and to create the new one...

Comment: @Sem: He says he intends using jQuery in the text, so...

Comment: @RickWeller By the looks of it you are not currently using jQuery just plain JavaScript. Are you planning on including jQuery? Because if you were using jQuery you could also re-factor a lot of your existing code to be simpler.

Comment: If your using document.createElement your not using jQuery at all.

Comment: As well as `document.getElementById("id")` w/ jQuery this is just `$("#id")` etc.

Comment: there is **one** line of sorta kinda jquery `$(document.getElementById(divId)).fadeOut(2000);`. why the op is using getelement inside of a jquery selector is beyond me...

Comment: the div id is bij2 and because i use the fadeout in the timer i used the getElementById. If this is wrong i am sorry. It is working so that is why i use it. What else should i do?

Comment: @RickWeller all of your `$(document.getElementById(divId))` can be replaced by `$("#" + divId)` or `$("#bij2")` or `$('#bij2')` anywhere you have `getElementById` can be simplified by using jquery selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really simple:

```
$('#bij2').replaceWith( newcontent );
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the `replaceWith` of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: He is using jQuery: "fade out the div using jQuery"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - The OP seems to mention using jQuery

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Though he did say `will fade out the div using jQuery` although wether not the OP actually understands also.

Comment: But looking at his code.. Would suggest he is not using jQuery.

Comment: @ Rahul: My apologies!! He did indeed say jQuery, despite apparently not using it anywhere. Odd.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah I wouldn't be surprised if the OP is confused more than anything. I would probably suggest that he isn't actually using jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: As AaronDigulla points out, he is. But why not, if it makes things simpler and gives what's desired?!

Comment: @Rahul It's generally considered bad karma. The OP may have specific reasons as to why he is or isn't using a specific library

Answer (score 1):

You are not using jQuery at all in your code. The error you make is that you don't replace the node but rather append the new one after it. The function you are looking for is `replaceChild`.

```
node.replaceChild(oldNode, newNode)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to replace div 2 with suppose a div 3

```
<div id="1"><div id = "2"></div></div>
```

you can use

```
$("#1").html('<div id="3"></div>')
```

or you can use

```
$("#2").replaceWith('<div id="3"></div>')
```

Answer (score 1):

You've said "using jQuery," but you don't seem to be using jQuery.

If you really are using / intend to start using jQuery, then [Rahul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668257/157247) is what you want.

If not, then you're looking for [`parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317), [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727), and [`removeChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1734834066), e.g.:

```
// Assuming olddiv refers to the old div
var parent = olddiv.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(newdiv, olddiv);
parent.removeChild(olddiv);
```

That inserts the new div in front of the old one, then removes the old one.

So perhaps:

```
function replacediv(oldid, id) {

    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.id = typeof id !== "undefined" ? id : oldid; // Use old ID if no new one specified
    newdiv.className = 'newclass';
    newdiv.style.float = "left";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "nothing";

    var olddiv = document.getElementById(oldid);
    var parent = olddiv.parentNode;
    parent.insertBefore(newdiv, olddiv);
    parent.removeChild(olddiv);
    alert(id + 'gemaakt');
}
```

...and then call it with the old ID and the new one.

As a side note: You don't have to use `setAttribute` for `id`. It's a reflected property on the element instance.

Comment: `var olddiv = document.getElementById("bij2");` :)